# Getting error in flutter dart application. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code. I tried using data() instead but that didn't work either.

```
  Future getUserInterests(userId) async {
    User currentUser = User();

    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then((user) {
      currentUser.name = user['name'];
      currentUser.photo = user['photoUrl'];
      currentUser.gender = user['gender'];
      currentUser.interestedIn = user['interestedIn'];
    });
    return currentUser;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call [data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) in order to get to the data inside the [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = user.data();
currentUser.name = data['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

what firebase package version are you running? The new version changed the operator `[]` and getter `data` for the method `get()` and `data()` respectively

```
Future getUserInterests(userId) async {
User currentUser = User();

await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then((user) {
  Map<String, dynamic> doc = user.data();
  currentUser.name = doc['name'];
  currentUser.photo = doc['photoUrl'];
  currentUser.gender = doc['gender'];
  currentUser.interestedIn = doc['interestedIn'];
});
return currentUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are treating the `user` variable as if it was a `Map<String, dynamic>` (using the `[]` accessor notation), but the error tells you that it is an instance of `DocumentSnapshot`.

Not sure what field `DocumentSnapshot` has (what library are you using ?). You should check the documentation of whichever library you are using to find out how to access the fields you need.